# SELECT statement to select from multiple tables referenced by ROWIDs

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a small SQLITE 3 database accessed by AutoIt. Works all great, but now I need a more complex statement and maybe I now regret that I have referenced tables using only the ROWID instead of particular ID fields...

This is the configuration:

```
Table 1 Person
Name (string)
Initials (string)

Table 2 Projekte
Description (string)
Person (containing the ROWID of table Person)

Table 3 Planungen
ProjID (contains ROWID of table Projekte)
PlID (numeric, main selection identifier)
(plus some other fields that do not matter)
```

Initially, I only needed to read all data from table 3 Planungen filtered by a specific PlID. I did that successfully by using:

```
SELECT ROWID,* FROM Planungen WHERE PlID=[FilterValue1] ORDER BY ROWID;
```

Works great.

Now, I need to SELECT only a subset of these records, where PlID=[FilterValue1] and where ProjID points to a table 2 Projekte entry, that complies to Projekte.Person=[FilterValue2]. So I do not even need table 1 (Person), just 2 and 3.

I thought I could do it that way (now it becomes obvious, I am SQL idiot):

```
SELECT ROWID,* FROM Planungen p, Projekte pj WHERE pj.Person=[FilterValue2] and p.ProjID=pj.ROWID and p.PlID=[FilterValue1] ORDER BY ROWID;
```

That runs into an SQLite Error telling me that there is *no such column ROWID*. Oops! Really? How can that be? I can't use ROWID in the WHERE clause?? Well, probably it won't do what I intent anyway.

Can someone please help me? Can this be done without changing the database structure and introducing ID fields?

It would be great if the output of the SELECT would be identical to the first, working SELECT command, just with the additional "filtering" applied.

Answer (score 0):

You really should add a proper INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column to your tables. (The implicit `rowid` might be changed by a [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html).)

Anyway, this query fails because the column name `rowid` is ambiguous. Replace it with `pj.rowid` (or whatever table you want to access).